# Ellipse Function Acting Strangely in Processing

Tags: java, animation, processing, ellipse

I'm working on a sketch in processing where I need to have two ellipses in processing swap back and forth. This is being scaled up to have many cells on a grid swapping colors back and forth.

What's strange is I can have one cell moving back and forth between two places but the second I add in a second fill and ellipse function, my cells just stay in the same place.

What's interesting is I've printed out the color values, locations, etc and they toggle as expected. Am I missing something fundamental here? It's driving me crazy.

Here is the portion of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
void draw(){

 swapAgents(People, nc, 1000);


 background(255);

 int col1 = People.get(nc).col;
 int col2 = People.get(1000).col;

 fill(col1);
 ellipse(People.get(nc).location.x, People.get(nc).location.y, 10, 10);

 fill(col2);
 ellipse(People.get(1000).location.x, People.get(1000).location.y, 10, 10); 

 time_delay(1);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debug coordination of second ellipse? Looks to me like problem inside `People` or with `swapAgents` method.

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to debug your code if you don't post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So I figured it out! I was swapping all of the object properties (color and location). If you swap both those things for two objects then you will end up with two stationary ellipses. I needed to swap either the locations or the colors. Thanks for the feedback. Apologize for not giving more info in the initial post.